# Register script on the homepage too

Tags: php, wordpress

i have this function and i need it to work on homepage too, i tried to add

```
is_home() || is_front_page()
```

i got and error

```
            if ( function_exists( 'is_product' ) && is_product() || is_shop() || is_product_category()  ) {

                $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );

                $enabled = apply_filters( 'qlwcajax_product_enabled', '__return_true', $product );

                if ( ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) || $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) && $enabled ) {
                    wp_enqueue_script( 'woo-ajax-add-to-cart' );
                }
            }
```

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_type() on bool in C:\Users\vykin.VYK\Local Sites\diamond\app\public\wp-content\plugins\woo-ajax-add-to-cart\woo-ajax-add-to-cart.php on line 76
( ! ) Error: Call to a member function is_type() on bool in C:\Users\vykin.VYK\Local Sites\diamond\app\public\wp-content\plugins\woo-ajax-add-to-cart\woo-ajax-add-to-cart.php on line 76

```
if ( function_exists( 'is_product' ) && is_product() || is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
```

Comment: So it means `$product = wc_get_product($post->ID);` returns false. Do you have `$product` in front page?

Comment: I have products, i added wp_query to display them